# MYSQL - SUM of records of latest date grouped by customer

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5hO0.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAWLT.png)

Would like to build a query to fetch closing for each customer Which is sum(closing) for the latest date.

Could you please help me?

Comment: put your desire result here too

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post the expected outcome and the code you tried.

Comment: @axiac Sorry i am new here. Have added the images

Comment: @VinodNadar It was better the first time, the image was visible, now one have to click and open it in a new tab. But it's even better to put the text as text.

Comment: @axiac It says since i am a new user, i cannot embeed images. I am confused. Will learn thanks

Comment: @VinodNadar don't embed images and also don't link images when they are not needed. If you want to post several rows from your table then put the data as text and format it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the onslaught of downvotes, one approach is to use a subquery to restrict the sum of closing to the latest date for each customer.

```
SELECT
    t1.customer_id,
    SUM(closing) AS closing_sum
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT customer_id, MAX(entry_dt) AS max_entry_dt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY customer_id
) t2
    ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id AND
       t1.entry_dt    = t2.max_entry_dt
GROUP BY t1.customer_id
```

Comment: This gives the exact result. Just that instead of entry_dt, need to consider created_dt. Would make the changes and implement... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

@tim

I have modified the query as below.

```
SELECT
    a.customer_id,
    SUM(closing) AS closing_sum
FROM empty_accounting a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT customer_id, MAX(created_dt) AS max_created_dt
    FROM empty_accounting
    GROUP BY customer_id
) b
    ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND
       a.created_dt = b.max_created_dt
GROUP BY a.customer_id
```

But i am worried if the created_dt differs in seconds, it wont be summed.

Is there a way to find the entry_dt of the latest created_dt and then sum the closing of the entry_dt for each customer?

Note: entry_dt is the date when the transaction happened in real-life
and created_dt is the date when the record was created in the system. So i feel better to find the latest record using the created_dt field

Comment: This isn't how Stack Overflow works.  If my answer is right, or nearly solves your problem, then you should mark it correct.